# How to set full Screen Mode of My App which is made in netbeans platform?

Tags: java, netbeans, platform

I m made Desktop App in netbeans platform in java.now wwhen i run my app it will open by default size of netbeans platform configuration.but i want full screen mode when i run or startup my app. so where and how to do that in my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to open the JFrame maximized by default in swing you can use `JFrame. setExtendedState()`, illusrated below:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame{ 
   public MyFrame() {

       // Other codes 

       // Set the JFrame to maximize by default on opening
       setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);        

       // Rest of the program
    }
}
```

Also remember that you should not have `JFrame.pack()` or `JFrame.setMaximimumSize()` or `JFrame.setSize()` in the same menthod (here constructor).

Answer (score 3):

Use this code on Constructor.

```
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

ater using this whatever frame i have designed, that components are not fix in center or means disbalanced all the content that are designed using netbeans drag and drop

Answer (score 1):

If you want you Application to be Full Screen..Use **Toolkit**...

```
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();

int ScreenWidth = d.width;

int ScreenHeight = d.height;

myframe.setSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);

myframe.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in constructor

```
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using JFrames for your App.

```
// to start with
JPanel myUI = createUIPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(myUI);

// .. and later ...

JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
newFrame.setUndecorated();
newFrame.add(myUI);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xsize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    int ysize = (int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight();
    this.setSize(xsize, ysize);
```

Comment: Please add some description. Including where to use this code or how it will solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Netbeans** then after `initcomponent()` method you can use this code, it will help you out:

```java
setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` after `initComponents();`

For Example:

```
public YourForm() {
        initComponents();
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
```