# Name of the default, main frame in java (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I was just reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311764/how-to-set-full-screen-mode-of-my-app-which-is-made-in-netbeans-platform) SO page about how to set frames to full screen, so i saw my navigator:
[image: Navigator]

Here i have the main frame "[JFrame]" I think it has no name. Like you can see in the other ones, they have names namely, "Blank", "Main" and "See". But the major one has no name. So how to access that?
like to execute lines like:

```
myframe.setSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
```

I can use blank..... for the blank jframe but how to use it on the main one?

Forgive me if i sound stupid, i am new to java.

Comment: Can you re-word and clarify your question for us?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think that now you are able to get the question... see the answer; i am asking a way to refer to that jFrame. If you think that i there is some way to edit its grammer to make it more readable; please go ahead i would love to accept a edit from you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? And why are you using so many `JFrame`s? Why not use `JDialogs`?

Comment: @peeskillet See, i am a c programmer; i got a task to make a program in java in netbeans; i dont know much of it. But i work with the gui use C coding logics and check for the syntax, so i dont know much depth of java. what i am doing is; i have a lot of screens to work on: it is a big sort of software. i have made 12 java files and 3-4 frames in each of them. It is like 1st login in 1 java file and then choose what to do and then according to what you choose it opens that java file. All are mostly same (except 10-20 lines of code) and in each one i have 3-4 frames for different screens..

Comment: @peeskillet 1st screen in them takes 3 input values from users. and then there are two screen(jframes) are there for 2 different ways in which they can take the output. It would be great if you could chat with me and tell me how to improve the code or if it is then how to use ``JDialogs`` instead of jFrames

Comment: So your question has _nothing_ to with setting the size of the screen am I correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45473/discussion-between-peeskillet-and-daksh-shah)

Comment: @nachokk The answer i got was satisfactory; my real question was just, on how to refer to that jFrame; but it was kind of peeskillet to tell me that i should use something else instead of jframes, therefore i asked him how to do that; so that i can improve my program...

Comment: @DakshShah yeah , let's remove unnecesary comments :)

Comment: @peeskillet Hey! IF you are busy and cannot help no problem. Atleast reply plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans gui editor (a.k.a Matisse) when you create a `JFrame Form` always creates a subclass of the component (in your example JFrame). So your class is like

```
public MyClass extends JFrame
```

And in the gui editor you see as its base class `JFrame` then you just can refer with `this`

Example :

```
this.setSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
```

or

```
setSize(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
```