# How can I make a JFrame to go fullscreen after clicking the default fullscreen button?

Tags: java

I want to build a JFrame with a default size. But After the default fullscreen button is clicked, the frame will cover the full screen of monitor & what's inside the frame will readjust itself with the new frame size.

My question is how can I do that?

Here is the code i have written so far.

```
public class ApplicationFrame extends JFrame{
private static ApplicationFrame ref;

private ApplicationFrame(){
    ref=this;
    this.setTitle("Business Management");
    this.setBounds(50, 50, 1400, 800);
    this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static ApplicationFrame getRef(){
    if(ApplicationFrame.ref==null)
        new ApplicationFrame();
    return ref;
}
}
```

**Here is the picture of the button I am talking about
[image: **Here is the picture of the button I am talking about]

Comment: Where is the button??

Comment: If you want that your frame's component adjust themselves with frame's size you would need to use a layout manager and thats it.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the post and add the image.

Comment: Do you want to maximize or go into fullscreen mode?

Comment: Currently what happens if you click on that button i think it might maximise it.

Comment: This is what the icon is already doing, it is a "maximize" button. This is unclear. Now, if you have a problem with the components not reorganizing, you have a  `Layout` problem

Comment: I think I want to maximize it according to the monitor size and the components in this frame like buttons, lebels etc will readjust themselves according to that.

Comment: possible duplicate for this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311764/how-to-set-full-screen-mode-of-my-app-which-is-made-in-netbeans-platform

Comment: you can also restrict user by setSize() of JFrame method for not going into hustle of readjusting Frame's components.

Comment: @rashedhassan use a layout manager for that.

Comment: but after I click the button frame is maximized but the components stay in there previous locations.

Comment: Which layout manager you are using

Comment: See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). This is the problem, not the maximze action of the `JFrame`, you just didn't composed the layout correctly. Or not at all, the `JFrame` I see is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFrame will do this automatically when you click the button, unless you prevent it from doing it (for example, by set frame.setMaximumSize).

However, for the contents of the JFrame to render properly, you need to correctly use the LayoutManagers (FlowLayout, BoxLayout, etc).

By default, JFrame uses BorderLayout, which allows you to add components to the borders (left, right, top, bottom, center).
A good practice is to add a JPanel on the border, and add your components inside this JPanel.

Comment: This is a good example to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try this.